# Posting syslog messages to a syslog server from Android

Tags: android, udp, syslog

Is there a library that can help with that or do I have to set this up? (the UDP network connection and so on)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think constructing a syslog message and sending it out over a java.net.DatagramSocket is only a few lines of code.

Comment: Thansk, i've implemented it using the datagramSocket a few weeks back